# Where to report and discuss UI "bugs" and inconstancies?

Tags: interface, documentation

As UI/design inconstancies are not considered bugs (rightly so), they are off topic on the bug tracker.

Is there a place where these sorts of things can be reported and discussed? 
Or a place to write issues/ideas where the [new UI team](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/11/18/blender-foundation-announces-user-interface-team/) will read them?

Comment: I believe [this wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Proposals/UI) was created for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a full proposal (detailed design docs), <strike>it should be ok to open a task on http://developer.blender.org/ and discuss there</strike> *(staff only!)*

You can discuss with the community at http://blenderartists.org/ to generate ideas, exchange mockups and find to a practical proposal. Then it's time to write it down on a wiki page for example.

Implement the ideas or find someone who does, then submit something working (a patch/diff) to the [tracker](https://developer.blender.org/differential/diff/create/). If there's no one to actually code it, it will likely be considered a feature request and not gain much attention there are just too many and not everyone will agree on a certain solution...

Comment: Only team members are suppose to create tasks. This is to avoid an influx of tasks and such.

Instead the WIKI should be used to create a proposal. Then attention can be brought to the proposal via IRC, the BF-UI mailing list, or feel free to tweet me directly @carter2422

Comment: Updated answer, left "open a task" part in with a giant strikethrough line, to make things clear :) Thank you for your additions about the communication channels, upvoted!

Comment: The question was about inconsistency, not UI design proposal. I understand UI proposal should not be made by everyone to prevent influx, but inconsistencies are not subjective that much. Adding a new type 'inconsistency' in the bugtracker, would greatly help improve the UI. Team members are experienced users and experienced users don't see inconsistencies anymore.

Comment: Well, I guess there are two types of inconsistencies: a) slips of the pen (or rather coding fingers), where there's no doubt how to correct it (like misspellings). b) Inconsistencies by design, something not nice but unavoidable unless the groundlaying design is changed. I had the latter on mind, and these really need proper proposals how to solve the problem, not only a bug report saying it exists and that it shouldn't be like that.