# Cycles Materials: Listing shader nodes in a consistent way

Tags: interface, node-editor

Is there a way to re-arange the listing of shader nodes? It seems like they are listed in a random and inconsistent way, so that finding the shader you need is not very efficient.

Examples:
Choosing from the material tab in 2.71 I get this list of shader nodes:

[image]

In the node editor by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> I get the shader list appearing in this order:

[image]'

In 2.70 I get:

[image]

It drives me nuts! Is there a way to shuffle the list in alfabetical order or in a more rational way?

Comment: +1 to this. I've also noticed this, and I also find it annoying as it messes with the "menu hotkeys" (you can press the first letter of a menu item to select that item). So G in the node editor gives you a glossy node, and G in the properties editor gives you a glass node. I'm pretty sure this isn't changeable without changing the source code (unless there is some python hack). Imho this is an [interface bug](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6804/599) and should probably be changed in the source code. You could try the wiki or the mailing list, the mailing list seems to get more attention.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks about adding features not yet in Blender. These should instead be posted on the [requests section of the blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Requests) or in the [bf-functionality mailing list](http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-funboard).

Comment: I've [asked on the mailing list about this](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2014-June/043817.html), and it seems to be a known issue.