# Shortcut key for smooth shading

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

In edit mode I can press <kbd>W</kbd> to bring up the specials menu, then <kbd>D</kbd> to shade smooth. Is there any shortcut key for *shade smooth* in object mode? I know I can assign a key, but wanted to know if there already is one in blender.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. There is not.

There are two good places to look for shortcuts. The <kbd>Space</kbd> menu, and the user preferences.

[image]

If there were shortcuts, they would show up there:

[image]

Comment: is there a good way to find the shortcuts, like I described in the question? I haven't found them using ether method you suggested.

Comment: @David I'm not sure what you mean.. What shortcuts? There aren't any shortcuts for smooth shading by default.

Comment: "W" then "D" is what I was referring to. I do not know of any way to find the shortcuts for items that are in a menu.

Comment: @David Those shortcuts are based on the letters in the name of the operator. The letter used as the shortcut is underlined.

Comment: I know, and I thought that that might be your next comment. What I meant is with the 2 methods you mentioned is there any way to find those shortcuts?

Comment: @David No, as they aren't really stored like normal shortcuts. I actually don't think they are stored at all, but I don't know this for sure. Here's an [example of why I think this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13376/599). You might be able to write some python script to get all the operators and their menus, then figure out what letter their shortcut will be, but IMO it's just easier to look at the underlined letters in the menu entry for operators you find yourself using often.

Answer (score 4):

You can set hotkeys like shown in this example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on any button and create shortcut

[image]